# How to request url and download folders with python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I'm trying to request an URL (thanks to an id stored in a postgresql data base) which sends me zip folders with several files inside.

```
import psycopg2
import requests

url = "https://myurl/"
conn = psycopg2.connect(user="XXX", password="XXX", database="XXX", host="localhost", port="5432")
print("Successfully connected!")
cur = conn.cursor()
sql ="select id from public.base"
cur.execute(sql)

row = [item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]

for d in row:
   requests.post(url+d)
```

The requests.post(url+d) is working, i have a 200 response.

But I don't know how to do the following steps, that is to say to upload in my workspace these zip folders...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `zipfile` & `io` library for that, specifying your download location within a `extractall`, like so :)

```
from psycopg2 import (
    connect,
    OpertionalError,
)
from zipfile import (
    BadZipFile,   
    ZipFile,
)
from io import BytesIO
import requests


def download_zip(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.ok:
        try:
            z = ZipFile(BytesIO(response.content))    
            z.extractall("/path/to/destination_directory")
        except BadZipFile as ex:
            print('Error: {}'.format(ex))

        print('Download succeeded: {}'.format(url))
    else:
        print('Connection failed: {}'.format(url))


def main():
    conn = connect(
        user='XXX',
        password='XXX',
        database='XXX',
        host='localhost',
        port='5432',
    )
    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('select id from public.base')
    except OperationalError:
        exit(0)
    
    row = [item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]
    
    for id in row:
        download_zip('https://myurl/{}'.format(id))
    
    print('Download completed')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ! Your first script is working I juste have a problem of memory, I will try with a 64 bit version of Python...

Comment: the script of D Silveiro is working but after 15h of downloading an error appears :

`raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`

But actually the following url give a zip file... so I don't understand why it says that it is not a zip file...

Comment: @MrGreedy Introduced error handling for malformed/invalid zip files, should be okay now :)

Comment: @MrGreedy If that fixes the problem feel free to mark the question as resolved when you get some time :)

Comment: Yes Thanks for your help @D Silveiro :) !